# Microsoft Graph - Outlook Api - How to get the id of the event created?

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

I create a outlook calendar event just like that with success.

```
await 'clientForRequest'.Me.Calendars['calendario_id'].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
```

If I get the id of the `@event` with `@event.id` it gives me `null`.

If I set the id of the `@event` before the request (to Add an Event) with a random string base 140 (witch I saw in "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#" with some events that I created), the id of the event is set to the calendar Outlook with a diferent id.

How I properly get the id of the event that I create with that request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning the results of `AddAsync()` to `@event`. You need to assign it yourself:

```cs
@event = await 'clientForRequest'
  .Me
  .Calendars['calendario_id']
  .Events
  .Request()
  .AddAsync(@event);
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
await 'clientForRequest'.Me.Calendars['calendario_id'].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
```

Executing the code snippet you wrote above should return an event object of the event created.

Therefore, you can get the event id as follows,

```cs
Event createdEvent = await 'clientForRequest'.Me.Calendars['calendario_id'].Events.Request().AddAsync(@event);
Console.WriteLine(createdEvent.Id);
```